# Timestamps with SVN (using BBedit/Texmate)

Tags: timestamp, textmate, bbedit

Is there a way to auto insert a time stamp into a document (html/css/ 
js/php/pl/txt) with every commit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Subversion's *[Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)*. First you must set the `svn:keywords` property on any files you want the substitution to occur on:

```
% svn propset svn:keywords "Date" /path/to/file
```

Then in your sourcecode, include the following:

```
$LastChangedDate$
```

There are other useful substitution keywords available such as `Id` which includes a combination of the revision, the modification date, and the user who made the commit.

Comment: Thanks Amit. That works and Cornerstone made it even easier in their UI.